# Using <xsl:choose> to select true or false in xsl

Tags: xslt-1.0

First if I have posted wrongly then I apoligies...ok I am looking for assistance on how to use a xsl file to be able to select either one or another  using the following in the xsl by selecting say true/false will to icall it...any help be greatful as just getting started in understand xsl

```
<xsl:choose>  
<li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
<xsl:otherwise>
<li><a href="#" id="current">Products</a></li>
```

Can this be done say by selecting if true

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:choose>  
> <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
> <xsl:otherwise>
> <li><a href="#" id="current">Products</a></li>
> ```

**This is syntactically ilegal and also meaningless**.

A syntactically correct and meaningful example of **[`xsl:choose`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose)** is:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="someCondition">  
   <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <li><a href="#" id="current">Products</a></li>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**The best recommendation for a novice is to read good books on XSLT and XPath**.

**One list of good resources can be found here**:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589